# How to get dom event reference while in c# context

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

I am writing a modal component for blazor but i am struggeling to find a solution which fulfills the requirement to do both at the same time:

- close ONLY when clicked outside modal content
- update C# object state (Visibility flag) accordingly

### scenario 1

If i use the C# based approach with `@onclick="WrapperClicked"` i can update the Visibility state very easy, but struggle to get the DOM click event and therefore cannot distinguish between a wrapper and a wrapper content click.

The c# MouseEventArgs do not contain properties to distinguish the clicked dom element.

### scenario 2

Is based around uncommenting the code for

```
private Dictionary<string, object> ComponentValues()
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    // if(CloseOnModalFrameClickInternal)
    //  values.Add("onclick", "Amusoft.Components.ModalDialog.closeEvent(this, event);");
    
    return values;
}
```

With this version it is simple to get access to the dom click event - but i cannot pass a DotNetObjectReference to that handler, to be able to call back into c# and update my components state.

## Question

Does anyone have ideas how to resolve this deep interop scenario?

typescript code to distinguish wrapper click from wrapper content click:

```
        public static closeEvent(dotNetHelper: any, event: MouseEvent): void {
            console.log(event);
            console.log(dotNetHelper);
            
            let target = event.target as HTMLElement;
            if(target != null && target?.classList?.contains("amu-modal-wrapper")){
//              element.style.setProperty("display", "none");
                console.log("breakpoint landed");
//              valueOfReference.invokeMethodAsync("JsSetVisibility", false);
            }
        }
```

Additional Scss code compared to default code:

```
.amu-modal-wrapper {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;

    .amu-modal-content {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: orange;
    }
}
```

Modal component code:

```
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@implements IDisposable

<div @ref="wrapper" class="amu-modal-wrapper" @attributes="ComponentValues()" @onclick="WrapperClicked" style="padding: @(Padding)px; display: @(VisibleInternal ? "block" : "none")">
    <div class="amu-modal-content">
        <h3>@Headline</h3>
        @ChildContent
    </div>
</div>

@code {

    private ElementReference wrapper;
    private DotNetObjectReference<ModalDialog> _self;

    [Parameter]
    public string Headline
    {
        get => HeadlineInternal;
        set => HeadlineInternal = value;
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> HeadlineChanged { get; set; }

    private string _headlineInternal;

    private string HeadlineInternal
    {
        get { return _headlineInternal; }
        set
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(_headlineInternal, value))
                return;
            _headlineInternal = value;
            HeadlineChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public IJSRuntime JsRuntime { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public int Padding { get; set; } = 100;


    [Parameter]
    public bool Visible
    {
        get => VisibleInternal;
        set => VisibleInternal = value;
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> VisibleChanged { get; set; }

    private bool _visibleInternal;

    private bool VisibleInternal
    {
        get { return _visibleInternal; }
        set
        {

            if (EqualityComparer<bool>.Default.Equals(_visibleInternal, value))
                return;
            _visibleInternal = value;
            VisibleChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public bool CloseOnModalFrameClick
    {
        get => CloseOnModalFrameClickInternal;
        set => CloseOnModalFrameClickInternal = value;
    }

    private Dictionary<string, object> ComponentValues()
    {
        var values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        // if(CloseOnModalFrameClickInternal)
        //  values.Add("onclick", "Amusoft.Components.ModalDialog.closeEvent(this, event);");
        
        return values;
    }

    private bool CloseOnModalFrameClickInternal { get; set; } = true;

    public void Hide()
    {
        VisibleInternal = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        VisibleInternal = true;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _self = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
        if (firstRender)
            JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Amusoft.Components.ModalDialog.initialize", wrapper);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _self?.Dispose();
    }

    private Task WrapperClicked(MouseEventArgs arg)
    {
        JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Amusoft.Components.ModalDialog.closeEvent", _self, arg);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You dont need Java.**

```
 <div class="modal-outer" @onclick="OnBackgroundClicked">
        <div class="modal-inner" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
```

From my [repo](https://github.com/BrianLParker/HowToModal/blob/master/BlazorModals/Views/Components/ModalLauncher.razor)

It is now a free [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazorModals/) package as of about 24hrs ago

Comment: +1 for that since you resolved my specific issue with this, but keep the answer unresolved, because there are more generic issues around the dom event topic. Thanks a lot!